# defining relationships in Backbone-Relational -- not sure which direction the options are pointing?

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm having a heckuva time understanding the [documentation for Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#readme); it's not 100% clear on which relation to add things like `includeInJSON`. Probably best to describe my confusion by illustrating the structure I'm trying to create. I have a `Venue` model that has zero or more nested `Address` models (1:n relationship). The backend store is MongoDB, which can have embedded objects. I'd like to store it in this format:

```
{
    id: 12345,
    label: 'OPUS Cafe Bistro',
    addresses: [
        {
            type: 'mailing',
            address1: '#52 - 650 Duncan Ave',
            city: 'Penticton, BC'
        },
        {
            type: 'main',
            address1: '#106 - 1475 Fairview Rd',
            city: 'Penticton, BC'
        }
    ]
}
```

(Please ignore the ugly data structures; I've adjusted it for brevity.) Now I believe I set up the relationship between `Venue` and `Address` thusly:

```
var Venue = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'addresses',
            relatedModel: 'Address',
            includeInJSON: false,
            collectionType: 'Addresses',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'venue'
            }
        }
});
```

If I understand correctly, I set `includeInJSON` to false in order to prevent the `Venue` from being serialised into the `venue` key in `Address`, but under reverseRelation I leave `includeInJSON` blank in order to have the full `Address` (without a venue property) serialised as an array in the `addresses` property of the `Venue` – as per my hoped-for example. Correct?

By the same token, I'm trying to understand the same concept in relation to a join-style relationship. Consider that `Venue` now has an `organisationID` field:

```
/* venue in JSON format  */
{
    id: 12345,
    organisationID: 336,
    label: 'OPUS Cafe Bistro',
    addresses: []
}

/* and now for the organisation */
{
    id: 336,
    label: 'OPUS Entertainment Group'
}
```

Using the examples in the documentation, which seem to prefer the `Backbone.HasMany` relationship, I think that I'd have to set up `Organisation` thus:

```
var Organisation = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone:HasMany,
            key: 'venues',
            relatedModel: 'Venue',
            includeInJSON: Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute,
            collectionType: 'Venues',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'organisationID',
                includeInJSON: false
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

... which should serialise into the above example, right? (I.e., `Venue` grabs `Organisation`'s `id` and inserts it into `organisationID`, and `Organisation` doesn't serialise any list of `Venues`)

Thanks in advance for any help – looking forward to using this handy library, after clawing my eyeballs out trying to write my own relational glue for Backbone.js :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(copying my answer from https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/37 over here, so more people can hopefully find it)

I'm sure you've figured it out by now, sorry for replying so late, but just to be sure: options (like `collectionType` and `includeInJSON`) apply to the `key` that's within the same object.

So, for your first example, you could write the relation as:

```
var Venue = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'addresses',
            relatedModel: 'Address',
            includeInJSON: true,
            collectionType: 'Addresses',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'venue',
                includeInJSON: 'id'
            }
        }
});
```

This will create a  Venue that `HasMany` `addresses`. The `addresses` key for any given Venue uses the `collectionType` `Addresses`, and is fully serialized because `includeInJSON` is set to `true` (not that the default value for `includeInJSON` is also `true`; so if you don't specifiy it, it will fully serialize a `relation` or `reverseRelation`).

The `reverseRelation` simply takes the same options, only applies them with respect to the `venue` key on any Address. In this case, it will only serialize the `venue.id` property for the venue it's linked to.

Comment: wow! thanks for discovering my double-post and taking the time to update my question here!